# How to make an Hello Word with Assimp on Windows

Tags: java, c++, netbeans-8, assimp

I'm using Netbeans and I am not really an expert in C/C++ language, but at least I managed to clone it and compile it successfully

I am trying to create a small [Hello Word](https://github.com/elect86/Test/blob/master/main.cpp) program in order to debug better Assimp to port it to [java](https://github.com/elect86/jAssimp).

I imported the `assimp\include` under the "C++ Compiler", "General", "Include Directories" and wrote the simplest main

The problem is that I get this error on the [Importer instantiation](https://github.com/elect86/Test/blob/master/main.cpp#L19) and on the [`importer.ReadFile`](https://github.com/elect86/Test/blob/master/main.cpp#L31):

```
:Importer::Importer()'

 relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Assimp::Importer::Importer()'
----
```

What is the problem?

Comment: This is clearly because of the pre-compiled libraries inside the Assimp.
Use Cmake to compile the libraries yourself and then try again.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have idea how I could do that.. Those libraries weren't compiled together when I built Assimp from sources?

Comment: Since it looks someone thought the solution I found for myself it is not really the real solution working for me, I'd add this comment in order to help anyone who might be in my same situation. Use the test scenario, it is preatty easy, you don't have to deal with all the shit of dependencies/dll/library and so on. It is already there, use the [utImporter.cpp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/test/unit/utImporter.cpp#L202-L230) last test, modify it based on your needs. The tests contains also a lot of different format models, really useful!